# How to get rid of box selection border of GridView UWP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have this gridview which works fine, but everytime I select an item I got this blue line around the item, how to remove it ?

```
<GridView Margin="5,15,0,0"  x:Name="List" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="List_SelectionChanged">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid  Margin="11">
                    <StackPanel BorderBrush="Black" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Image Width="150" Height="150" Source="{Binding Way}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid  MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The following fixed it for me:

```
<GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter
                SelectedBackground="Transparent"
                SelectedPointerOverBackground="Transparent"
                PressedBackground="Transparent"
                SelectedPressedBackground="Transparent"
                />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: This is the best way to do not overload the app, and just works even in WinUI

Comment: How do you apply this to every GridView using a resource dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

To remove the selection blue border of `GridView`, we can modify the template of `GridView`. To modify the template of GridViewItem, we can select the `GridView` in "**Document Outline**" and right click, then select "**Edit Additional Templates**"→ "**Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle)**" → "**Edit a Copy...**".

In the `Style`, there is a `ListViewItemPresenter` in it.

> When developing for Windows 10, use **ListViewItemPresenter** instead of [GridViewItemPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.gridviewitempresenter.aspx) in your item container style, both for [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx) and for [GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx).

For more info, see [ListViewItemPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.listviewitempresenter.aspx).

The color of blue line around the item is defined by `SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}"`. We can set the `SelectedBackground="Transparent"`, then there is no blue line around the item.

Comment: Hi, i just found `"SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush"` but not Transparent!

Comment: `SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush` is use the `ThemeResource`,  Transparent is a color.

Comment: I did change to `SelectedBackground="Transparent"` and still shows the blue stuff!

Comment: If the mouse cover on the selected item, it will show the blue stuff. If you want remove it. You can set `SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"`.

Comment: its not a mouse, Windows Mobile, i found this `CheckMode="Overlay"` if i change to InLine the blue line arround got bigger!

Comment: Please tell me the emulator version and the VS version or post your complete code.

Comment: I'm using physical device latest build, here is my code:[here](http://pastebin.com/2P2QUtcP)

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it. Although it's not difficult to change the style, this requires about 99% less xaml (and a bit more code) to accomplish. You will have to remove the SelectionChanged event, specify the data type for your DataTemplate and add a Tapped event to each item.

```
<GridView SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="YourType">
            <Grid  Tapped="Grid_Tapped_For_Every_Item">
               ...                   
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    ...
</GridView>

in code file:

private void Grid_Tapped_For_Every_Item(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e){

    var g = (Grid) sender;
    var myClass = (YourType)g.DataContext;
    //Do whatever you were going to do in the SelectionChanged event
}
```